# How can I read the PBS launch script of a job that is running?

Tags: pbs, torque

I am using /torque/4.2.5 to schedule my jobs and I need to find a way to make a copy of my PBS launching script that I used for jobs that are currently queueing or running. The plan is to make a copy of that launch script in the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

TORQUE has a [job logging feature](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/10-logging/enablingJobLogs.htm?TocPath=10.0%20Job%20logging%7C_____2) that can be configured to record job scripts used at launch time.

**EDIT**: if you have administrator privileges and want to read the file that is stored you can inspect TORQUE_HOME/server_priv/jobid.SC

TORQUE_HOME is usually /var/spool/torque but is configurable.